# dc.js DataTable custom formatting

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I am formatting a dc.js DataTable, and I want to know if there is a better approach.  I am currently trying to color rows in the output table based on data.  To do this, I am outputting the data, then running a renderlet on the data, which is coloring the output.

I am further hiding the column that had the data, because I don't want the column to display, I just needed it to determine the color for the row.  The process seems like a hack, so I was curious if anyone was custom formatting a DataTable in a more elegant way.

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
       var userChart = dc.dataTable('#company-chart')
      .dimension(company)
      .group(function (d) {
                return d.company;
            })
            .columns([
                function (d) {
                    return d.job_service_datetime;
                },
                function (d) {
                    return d.company;
                },
                function (d) {
                    return d.first_name;                 
                },
                function (d) {
                    return d.last_name;
                }
            ])
        .renderlet(function (table) {
                $("#company-chart tr").each(function (index, Element) {
                    switch ($(Element).children("td").last().text()) {
                        case "2":
                            $(Element).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            $(Element).css("background-color", "#F5CCCC");
                            break;
                    }
                    if ($(Element).children("td").length > 1) {
                        $(Element).children("td").last().css("display", "none");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Link to the  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08ruj6uq/12/)

Comment: I was waiting to see if anyone else responded, but as the maintainer of dc.js I can tell you that I haven't seen anything better. [Any ideas for improvements?](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new) PRs welcome!

Comment: For those who didn't have jQuery you can replace the **$("#company-chart tr").each(function (index, Element) { ...** with **d3.selectAll('#company-chart tr').each( function( d, index, j) { ...** inside the function use **this** instead of **Element**.